# Swift Combine: How can I create a reusable Publishers.Map to connect to multiple upstream Publishers?

Tags: ios, combine

I'm trying to wrap my head around Combine, and as I refactor code I'm running into some confusion when I try to re-compose to avoid repeating myself.

In this case, I have a value I want to update any time:

- A specific subject changes
- The app comes to the foreground
- A 3-second refresh timer fires

Since the 3-second refresh timer doesn't publish anything until the first time it fires, I'm assuming I need multiple publishers.

I'm always only using the value from the subject, and ignoring any values sent from the foreground notification and timer.

Here is some example code, where I am processing the value based on only one publisher:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class DataStore {

    @Published var fillPercent: CGFloat = 0

    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    // how much the glass can hold, in milliliters
    private let glassCapacity: Double = 500

    // how full the glass is, in milliliters
    private var glassFillLevelSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Double,Never>(250)

    // a publisher that fires every three seconds
    private let threeSecondTimer = Timer
        .publish(every: 3,
                 on: RunLoop.main,
                 in: .common)
        .autoconnect()

    // a publisher that fires every time the app enters the foreground
    private let willEnterForegroundPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)

    init() {
        // publisher that fires any time the glass level changes or three second timer fires
        let glassLevelOrTimerPublisher = Publishers.CombineLatest(glassFillLevelSubject, threeSecondTimer)
            // is there shorthand to only return the first item? like .map{ $0 }?
            .map { glassFillLevel, timer -> Double in
                return glassFillLevel
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        // publisher that fires any time the glass level changes or three second timer fires
        let glassLevelOrForegroundPublisher = Publishers.CombineLatest(glassFillLevelSubject, willEnterForegroundPublisher)
            .map{ glassFillLevel, notification -> Double in
                return glassFillLevel
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        // how can I define map and everything after it as something, and then subscribe it to the two publishers above?
        glassLevelOrTimerPublisher
            .map{ fillLevelInMilliliters in

                let fillPercent = fillLevelInMilliliters / self.glassCapacity

                return CGFloat(fillPercent)
            }
            .assign(to: \.fillPercent, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I think what I want to do here is somehow separate out `.map` and everything after it, and somehow subscribe that to both publishers above.

I tried this, as a way to isolate everything after `.map` to make it reusable:

```
    let fillPercentStream = Publishers.Map{ fillLevelInMilliliters in

        let fillPercent = fillLevelInMilliliters / self.glassCapacity

            return CGFloat(fillPercent)
        }
        .assign(to: \.fillPercent, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
```

But that gave me an error that said `Missing argument for parameter 'upstream' in call` so I tried adding something for that parameter, and ended up with this:

```
    let fillPercentStream = Publishers.Map(upstream: AnyPublisher<Double,Never>, transform: { fillLevelInMilliliters in

            let fillPercent = fillLevelInMilliliters / self.glassCapacity

            return CGFloat(fillPercent)
        })
        .assign(to: \.fillPercent, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Then, I end up in a chain of compiler errors: `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate` and it suggests I specify `-> CGFloat` in `.map`, which I added, but then it tells me I should change `CGFloat` to `_` and I end up with more errors.

Is this even something I'm supposed to be able to do with Combine? Am I going about this all the wrong way? How can I properly re-use the `.map` and `.assign` chain with two different publishers?

I'm somewhat new to Combine and reactive programming in general, so if you have other suggestions to improve how I'm doing everything here please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to map your timer publisher output to the subject's value, and also to map your notification publisher output to the subject's value. Then you can merge the subject, the timer, and the notification into a single publisher that publishes the subject's value when the subject's value changes and when the timer fires and when the notification is posted.

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        fractionFilled = CGFloat(fillSubject.value / capacity)

        let fillSubject = self.fillSubject // avoid retain cycles in map closures
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { _ in fillSubject.value }
        let foreground = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
            .map { _ in fillSubject.value }
        let combo = fillSubject.merge(with: timer, foreground)
        combo
            .map { [capacity] in CGFloat($0 / capacity) }
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.fractionFilled = $0 }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }

    let capacity: Double = 500
    @Published var fractionFilled: CGFloat

    private let fillSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(250)
    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
}
```

Comment: Wow, I recognize you from comments and answers I've come across during my Combine learning! This answer has some of subtle adjustments to how I was going about things beyond just answering the question, so I really appreciate that.

Comment: Is the use of `[capacity]` in `combo.map` a way to avoid retain cycles? I'm not familiar with that usage and thought it was some kind of array at first. I see that `.map { CGFloat($0 / self.capacity) }` works, but I'm guessing that would be bad for memory management?

Comment: @gohnjanotis it's called a capture list and you can either capture self (in a weak, strong or unowned way), or directly capture a list of dependencies. You can read more on it here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swifts-closure-capturing-mechanics/#weak-references-are-not-always-the-answer